# Flutter Cupertino/Material combined Theme / shared font family

Tags: flutter, dart, google-fonts, material-widget, cupertino-widgets

I've been trying to solve a couple of problems using both Material and Cupertino widgets.

1) I can't seem to figure out how to globally define a font family for both. Either I use a `CupertinoApp` and have the Cupertino widgets correct or `MaterialApp` and have the Material theme widgets correct.

2) How do I define the Cupertino `primaryColor` attribute without a `CupertinoTheme`?

I've found something called MaterialBasedCupertinoThemeData but I'm not sure how it works / can't find any docs/tutorials on it.

I can't find any other questions on the subject and would appreciate the help!

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoApp(
      title: 'betterfriend',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      // This lets us use material components
      localizationsDelegates: <LocalizationsDelegate<dynamic>>[
        DefaultMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        DefaultWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        DefaultCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],

      home: CupertinoTheme(
        data: MaterialBasedCupertinoThemeData(
          materialTheme: ThemeData(textTheme: Styles.textTheme),
        ),
        child: ScreenSwitcher(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Hi Jordan,

Can you post the codes?

Comment: I've added it to the post, but this is just me trying to get it working.